# IntelliSense extension for C/C++ error on windows 10

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw, intellisense

Installed VS code and MinGW on windows. Added IntelliSense extension for C/C++. I had added the path of gcc.exe from the bin. Typed a simple C program. It's showing an error. Please help!
Error is:

```
PS F:\C\Chapter 1> gcc 001_first.c
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also the problem is:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your include path. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit( Path is mentioned )
Cannot open source file "stdio.h"
```

Comment: Those two errors are unrelated. Only the second one is from the intellisense. The first one is from the compiler, complaining about a missing `main`.

Comment: How can I solve the second one?

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliSense error only means that VS Code can't find the header files. You need to set your include path. You can learn about it (and many others) [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp).

The second one is a bit more interesting. I also encountered it several times. The answer is: append `-mconsole` to the gcc command. It's because by default, it tries to build a desktop application, which requires `WinMain`.

Comment: I'm getting the output. But in the Problem area, the same lines are being displayed. Can't they be cleared?

Comment: I haven't seen a single distribution of MinGW that expects `WinMain` by default. I bet OP simply forgot `main`.